# WPF window freezing after sending file to dropbox

Tags: wpf, task, dropbox

My window is freezing after clicking "Send" button. It send file and then it should release GUI, but it doesn't. See my code:

```
    private void btn_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SBox.UploadFile("user", "service", 1, path.Text))
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Fail, try again");
    }
```

Then code from Sbox class:

```
    public static bool UploadFile(string user, string service, int orderId, string filepath)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        dbx = new DropboxClient(login_key);

        string path = "/Files/" + user + "/" + service + "/order - " + orderId + "/received";
        string fileName = now.Year + "" + now.ToString("MM") + "" + now.ToString("dd") + "" + Path.GetExtension(filepath);

        Task upl = Upload(dbx, path, fileName, File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)); //send file
        upl.Wait();

        return true;
    }
```

and task code:

```
    static async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, byte[] content)
    {
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(content))
        {
            var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
                folder + "/" + file,
                WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
                body: mem);
            Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
        }
    }
```

as I said, file is send to correct folder but GUI is freezing. Console app works perfectly, writing output when success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did play with it a bit and did some research. Here is my final working code
Button:

```
    private async void btn_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SBox sbox = new SBox();
        progress.Text = "Uploading file, please wait...";
        bool t = await sbox.UploadFromGUI("user", "service", 1, path.Text);
        progress.Text = "";
        if (t == true)
            MessageBox.Show("Success!", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Failed", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
```

and method in SBox class:

```
    public async Task<bool> UploadFromGUI(string user, string service, int orderId, string filepath)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        dbx = new DropboxClient(login_key);

        string path = "/files/" + user + "/" + service + "/order - " + orderId + "/received";
        string fileName = now.Year + "" + now.ToString("MM") + "" + now.ToString("dd") + "" + Path.GetExtension(filepath);

        try
        {
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)))
            {
                var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
                    path + "/" + fileName,
                    WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
                    body: mem);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using [Task.Wait()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) with `upl.Wait();`

This causes the current thread to run and wait until the task has completed before continuing.

**Edit:**

If you want to do more than that single method (perform other actions on completion) I've always used tasks like this with `Task.Run()`:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Upload(...);
    OnCompletion();
}
```

and if you want to do UI stuff, remember to call it on the dispatch thread:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Upload(...);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        OnCompletion();
    };
}
```

Comment: Run() doesn't exits as method. I just deleted upl.Wait() and it works, problem is, don't know when it finished uploading file.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I've always used Task.Run(method) but its actually a static method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You know when it's finished, you're writing to console "Saved..."

Comment: I added some more detail in the answer

Comment: i had to modify your code a bit to get it working, but it's not uploading files now and not dispatching changes:   

            SBox sbox = new SBox();
                 Task.Run(async () => {
                await sbox.UploadFromGUI("user", "service", 1, path.Text);
                await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    btn_send.Content = "Sent";
                }));
            }
            );

Comment: i can run it as a task as i have modified Task in my class a bit, so it uploads file, GUI not freezing, but no notification when finished   Task t = sbox.UploadFromGUI("user", "service", 1, path.Text);